# Genymotion file transfer taking too long

Tags: android, windows, genymotion

I've been trying to use the Genymotion emulator to test the Android applications developed on Windows. I could initialize a virtual device, but was unable to load an app into the emulator.

In the best case I successfully dragged "MyFirstApp" to an Android 2.3.3 Galaxy S2 emulator, but it took about 20 minutes to start running. After getting started, it ran normally.

What can be the cause of this problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that my problem was a service getting in conflict with Genymotion. That can be solved by performing a clean boot in Windows, as indicated here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135

I disabled all the services that were not from Microsoft, and it worked fine. Then, I started to enable again some of the services to find out which one was causing the problem.

It was a service named "Warsaw Technology", that is part of a security module for internet banking. This module is very used here in Brazil, in banks like Banco do Brasil, Itaú and Santander. A lot of people complain about this module, because it is very hard to remove, almost kind of a malware.